# Nhibernate and Security

Tags: nhibernate

Hi I am doing research for a paper that I am writing on security and Nhibernate...Does Nhibernate provide any security feature and how much is that efficient.if not can we use any security design pattern to over come those security flaws...

Answer (score 2):

IMO: Security is something that should be integral component of an application which is using nHibernate for data access. As far as I am concerened nHibernate is just a wrapper on top of Ado.Net APIs. If you write your nHibernate poorly then you can very well expose yourself to sql injection kind of security problems. If your application has good security then nHibernate's security problems will be hidden from outer world.

You can always write worst of code using best of tools and vice versa.

Comment: If you use parameters for your nhibernate queries you should be safe against sqlinjection. All other security concerns are as pradeep mentions not a business of nhibernate.